# What is the difference between base and evdev xkb rules?

Tags: xorg, xkb, libinput

I just switched from xf86-input-evdev to xf86-input-libinput and it broke my keyboard layout – arrow keys with right alt, context menu key, delete key, numpad enter, etc. all weirdly swapped. `libinput debug-events` showed correct key, though. After checking [`Xorg.conf`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/07bc859e9acec3cc6f7a8129e4b05a7584fef209/nixos/modules/services/x11/xserver.nix#L689), I noticed the following line:

```
Option "XkbRules" "base"
```

After changing it to `evdev`, the keyboard worked correctly.

I found “[The XKB Configuration Guide](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xorg-docs/input/XKB-Config.html#id2521360)” which mentions the various rules but does not go into details about their difference.

What is the difference between the two layouts? Is it okay to use the evdev rules even with libinput?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**tl;dr:** On Linux, you should be using the `evdev` rules.  As it says in the XKB guide you link:

> On Linux systems, the **evdev** rules are most commonly used, on other systems the **base** rules are used.

---

The difference is largely historical.  `evdev` is the modern Linux kernel input subsystem and did not exist when XKB was first written.  If you look into the source code for [xkeyboard-config](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/XKeyboardConfig/), you'll find that both `evdev` and `base` rules are generated from (mostly) the same templates.  Compare the generated files in your system XKB database with `diff`, though.  You'll see many entries where the `base` rules loads `inet` symbols for specific keyboard models, while the `evdev` rules do away with most of those model-specific entries and load a more generalized set:

```
/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base:
[...]
! model         =       symbols
  a4techKB21    =       +inet(media_nav_common)
  asus_laptop   =       +inet(media_common)
  acer_tm_800   =       +inet(acer_laptop)
  benqx730      =       +inet(benqx)
  btc9116u      =       +inet(btc9019u)
  chromebook    =       +inet(chromebook)
  dellsk8125    =       +inet(dell)
// and about 50 more lines
// generated from xkeyboard-config/rules/base.m_s.part

/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev
[...]
! model         =       symbols
  $evdevkbds    =   +inet(evdev)+inet(%m)
  chromebook    =   +inet(evdev)+inet(chromebook)
  applealu_jis  =   +inet(evdev)+macintosh_vndr/jp(alujiskeys)
  *             =   +inet(evdev)
// ...that's all.
// generated from xkeyboard-config/rules/evdev.m_s.part
```

No really, that's the whole model-to-symbols section from the `evdev` rules, whereas the `base` version is 60-odd lines long.  The `evdev.m_s.part` file is the source template for that section of the rules; it's a model-to-symbol mapping (the `!model = symbol` line at the start of that section; hence the `m_s` in the filename).  The only other evdev-specific section of the rules comes from the `evdev.m_k.part` file, which is a model-to-keycodes mapping (the `!model = keycodes` section of the rules), and the differences there are similar.

For further details, consult the **keycodes** and **symbols** files referenced by those rules (especially `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev` and `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/inet`).  You may be interested in [this writeup of the XKB rules format](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355404/222377).

Comment: I see the difference now, I still do not understand why base worked without libinput and does not with it, though.

Comment: could be an edge case that `libinput` isn't handling properly yet.  with full details of your configuration (exact XKB model, layout, variant, options, etc) one could do a full postmortem and determine an exact cause.  consider filing a bug with `xf86-input-libinput`.